Apollo Client - Recursively fetch all relay style paginated results
With apollo client, I'd like to fetch all data on a paginated query on page load. I essentially want to do:
1. Fetch initial data and page info
2. Fetch all subsequent data until there is no more pages left in page info
3. With all resultant data merge into the cached data

I am starting with something like:
const {
    data,
    loading,
    networkStatus,
    fetchMore,
  } = useCustomQuery({
    variables: {
      pageArgs: {
        first: 1,
      },
    },
    notifyOnNetworkStatusChange: true,
  });

const items =
    data?.customQuery?.edges.map((edge) => edge.node) || [];
const currentPageInfo = data?.customQuery?.pageInfo;
const nextCursor = data?.customQuery?.pageInfo.endCursor;
const hasNextPage = data?.customQuery?.pageInfo.hasNextPage;

useEffect(() => {
    if (
      networkStatus === NetworkStatus.ready &&
      hasNextPage
    ) {
      const variables = {
        after: nextCursor,
        first: 1, // TODO adjust to spec
      };
      fetchMore({
        variables,
        updateQuery(
          previousResult: CustomQuery,
          { fetchMoreResult },
        ) {
          if (!fetchMoreResult?.customQuery) {
            return previousResult;
          }


          return {
            ...previousResult,
            customQuery: {
              ...previousResult.customQuery,
              edges: [
                ...previousResult.customQuery.edges,
                ...fetchMoreResult.customQuery.edges.filter(
                  (edge) =>
                    !previousResult.customQuery.edges.some(
                      (prevEdge) => prevEdge.node.id === edge.node.id,
                    ),
                ),
              ],
              pageInfo: fetchMoreResult.customQuery.pageInfo,
            },
          };
        },
      });
    }
  }, [
    hasNextPage,
    nextCursor,
    networkStatus,
    fetchMore,
  ]);

I can't quite get it to work, it fetches twice but the data in the cache is the same object duplicated.
